# Firefox uses float coordinates in SVG paths

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, svg, raphael

I'm writing a [Paint](http://osxdaily.com/images/Paintbrush-small.png)-like thing in JavaScript using Raphael.js. 
The brush strokes are implemented via paths: each time the mouse moves, a new string like "L x, y" is appended to the 'current' path.

So for example, if I click and wiggle a little, this is what I get in Chrome:

```
<path style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: round;" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M173,326L173,326L175,325L180,322L186,318L195,312L204,303L213,294L219,285L221,283L224,281L225,280L226,280L229,280L232,280L238,282L243,288L250,296L256,305L263,311L268,316L272,318L273,318L276,318L278,318L281,318L286,316L294,309L300,301L307,292L314,281L321,272L326,265L328,261L329,257L332,251L333,249L334,249L335,248L337,248L339,248L342,249L346,252L351,256L356,260L360,262L364,264L368,264L370,265L374,265L377,264L380,262L387,257L394,251L403,245L411,235L420,226L429,217L437,208L446,202L453,200L461,198L466,198L470,198L472,198L474,199L477,202L478,205L479,209L483,214L487,219L491,221L494,225L498,226L502,226L505,226L506,226L508,226L509,226L510,226" stroke-width="30" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
```

Chrome uses *integers* for stroke coordinates, and it works like a charm, really smooth.

On the other hand, Firefox has a bad performance problem, as it seems it uses floats for the paths coordinates:

```
<path style="stroke-linejoin: round; stroke-linecap: round;" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M116,334.1333312988281L116,334.1333312988281L118,335.1333312988281L128,332.1333312988281L135,332.1333312988281L145,330.1333312988281L157,330.1333312988281L169,328.1333312988281L181,326.1333312988281L194,323.1333312988281L207,320.1333312988281L219,317.1333312988281L234,314.1333312988281L260,307.1333312988281L275,302.1333312988281L286,295.1333312988281L297,286.1333312988281L308,271.1333312988281L315,258.1333312988281L324,245.13333129882812L333,232.13333129882812L342,225.13333129882812L351,218.13333129882812L367,214.13333129882812L373,214.13333129882812L380,214.13333129882812L385,212.13333129882812L391,212.13333129882812L396,212.13333129882812L402,212.13333129882812L410,218.13333129882812L420,229.13333129882812L431,242.13333129882812L438,255.13333129882812L445,264.1333312988281L457,269.1333312988281L459,269.1333312988281L460,269.1333312988281L463,269.1333312988281L465,268.1333312988281L467,263.1333312988281L471,254.13333129882812L474,243.13333129882812L476,233.13333129882812L481,222.13333129882812L483,215.13333129882812L486,208.13333129882812L488,207.13333129882812L489,205.13333129882812L490,204.13333129882812" stroke-width="30" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
```

Is there a solution? I want Firefox to use integers too.

**EDIT**:

I found out that the manually added paths behave normally (i.e., use integers). The problem could be with the code that builds the strokes maybe?

```
$('#canvas_container').mousemove(function(e){
    var newx = e.pageX - $(document).scrollLeft() - $('#canvas_container').offset().left;
    var newy = e.pageY - $(document).scrollTop() - $('#canvas_container').offset().top;

    [...]

    if (brushing) {
      brush_current_stroke.attr({
        'path': [brush_current_stroke.attr('path'), 'L', newx, ' ', newy].join('')
      });
    }

    oldx = newx;
    oldy = newy;
  });
```

**EDIT**:

I changed the code that calculates the mouse coordinates to this:

```
var newx = Math.round(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
var newy = Math.round(e.pageY - $(this).offset().top);
```

Now Firefox uses integers for both coordinates too. However the performance problem persists! Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that SVG is supposed to give you floats back for everything. If you're getting integers from Chrome that must be some kind of optimization they have going.

Comment: Ooooh.. that's weird. Random thought based on no evidence whatsoever - is your viewbox 1:1 with your svg canvas or do you have transforms on the path?

Comment: [Uhm, sorry, I deleted the last comment, I thought I was mistaken but I wasn't] I don't know, I'm using Raphael, the Element.path() method

Comment: you're actually getting the coordinates from the the event objects and the document scrollposition it seems... so svg isn't the source of those coordinates... I'd suggest updating the question title to something more descriptive.